# exe created by cx-freeze gives me a error

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

**Log.py**

```
import logging 
import logging.handlers
class Log:    
    def __init__(self):
        FILENAME='LOG'
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
        logger = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(FILENAME,'midnight',1)
        root_logger.addHandler(logger)
        logging.getLogger('log')
```

**Main.py**

```
from Log import Log
import time 
import logging
log_obj = Log()
log = logging.getLogger('log')
log.info("Service Started")
while 1:
t=1
```

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Test",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Test",
    executables = [Executable("Main.py", base="Win32GUI")])
```

So this is the final code which I am using. EXE file got created but I am getting an error while running it.The error is "Nonetype object has no attribute type 'write'"

Waiting for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

Without a stack trace, i can only advise you to try base="Console".